# Build variants of ionic apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, gulp

What is the way to achieve build variants (like gradle flavors) with Ionic?

In my case I would like to use the same code base to build several apps with small differences such as colors, urls, labels, modules to be enabled, etc.

Any help, experience, or hint appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently doing something like you. I have done a Node.js script which creates some file config based on a list of apps/configs

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am working on the same but unable to find solution.